# gcc treat all warnings as errors EXCEPT X

Tags: gcc, warnings

For reasons best left unmentioned, I want to treat all warnings as erros, except for a single warning (deprecated) which I would like to tread as a warning.

Is there any more convenient way to do this than listing out all the warnings I want to treat as errors by hand?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do `-Werror -Wno-error=deprecated`.