# Treat all warnings as errors, except some

Tags: visual-c++

In the answer to this question, [gcc treat all warnings as errors EXCEPT X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469906/gcc-treat-all-warnings-as-errors-except-x) it is shown how all warnings can be treated as errors except one.

First we add the compiler flag that treats all warnings as errors:

```
-Werror
```

Then we add exceptions to the above rule (in this case error called `deprecated`)

```
-Wno-error=deprecated
```

Is there a similar method in Microsoft Visual C++?

Comment: There's `/wd<warning>` for disabling a particular warning. I don't believe there's a switch to undo `/WX` for a specific warning (that is, still issue it, but as a warning rather than an error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

There was a user suggestion to add such a feature to Visual C++, but the item was closed by the Visual Studio Team (https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2597342-extend-c-to-treat-all-warnings-as-errors-except).

You can just treat specific warnings as errors: [Can I treat a specific warning as an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750880/can-i-treat-a-specific-warning-as-an-error)