# “Treat all warnings as errors except…” in C++/CLI project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, compiler-warnings, vcxproj

In C# projects (`.csproj` files), [it is possible to treat all warnings as errors *except a specific set of warnings*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267168/treat-all-warnings-as-errors-except-in-visual-studio). Typically, this makes sense for *obsolete*/*deprecated* warnings, as these are there specifically to *not* break a build while announcing an upcoming API change.

**Is the same also possible somehow for C++/CLI projects, i.e. in `.vcxproj` files?**

(I am referring to seeing [C4947](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4947?view=vs-2019) as a warning despite all other warnings being treated as errors.)

An [answer from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42886868/1430156) suggests it is not possible for plain C++ projects compiled by Microsoft's compiler by means of a compiler switch. However, I am hoping for the `.vcxproj` Xml format to support some element that causes such a behaviour.

I have tried inserting the `<WarningsNotAsErrors>4947</WarningsNotAsErrors>` element from the `.csproj` file into the `.vcxproj` file, but that won't help. Also, seeing that `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>` from the `.csproj` file is called `<TreatWarningAsError>` in `.vcxproj` (i.e. singular instead of plural), I tried `<WarningNotAsError>4947</WarningNotAsError>`, but to no avail.

I have read somehints about treating only specific warnings as errors, but this, of course, is not a viable solution. There are hundreds, if not thousands, of warnings (possibly even more in future compiler versions), *all* of which I want to treat as errors, *except* for a single one.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm currently in the *exact* same scenario.

Comment: @AaronBurke: No, for now, I assume/fear that I simply cannot do this for C++/CLI projects :/

Comment: Added full example of what seems to be the best we can do for now (currently with VS 2022 17.2, but haven't got the full setting we really want.

Answer (score -1):

We don't yet a have a complete and perfect answer to this. This is the best it seems we can do.

Have been wanting to do this as well, though more generally for C++.

Mainly for deprecating functions just like this post here, which has a couple of suggested workarounds.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/88ffa3e4-1ad4-410a-b50b-d6575cb914bd/override-wx-behavior-using-pragma-warning

Not sure whether it suits your situation.

Here is the best I can find to emit a message when the deprecated function is used, which if double clicking on will take you to that location.
It's still not a warning as far as the compiler is concerned though.

```
int my_function(int an_arg);

#define STRINGIFY_X(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_X(x)
#define DepFunc(Func) __pragma(message( __FILE__ "(" STRINGIFY(__LINE__) "): warning C4996: '" STRINGIFY(Func) "': My message about deprecated function." )) Func

#define my_function DepFunc(my_function)

// Can push and undefine so we don't get the message when we define the function
#pragma push_macro("my_function")
#undef my_function 

int my_function(int an_arg)
{
    return an_arg + 2;
}

#pragma pop_macro("my_function")

int some_situation()
{
    // use it somewhere
    return my_function(1); // line 50
}
```

Get message like this with the line where it is used.

```
C:\ ..\myFile.cpp(50): warning C4996: 'my_function': My message about deprecated function.
```

Comment: Have updated it to show full example of what seems to be the best we can do for now.